# Standardization and Normalization

Tags: classification, regression, normalization

Which and all Machine Learning algorithms needs the data to be standardised/normalised before feeding into the model. How do we determine whether the particular model/data needs to be  standardised/normalised.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have features that they have different scale and it is significant for some features, you should standardize your feature. Take a look at [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207108/179078).